# Rock Paper Scissors not printing output

Tags: java

So my program wont print *You win!* or *You lose! when I win the game or lose it*. My program only prints *Tie!* if the game is a tie. I am new to programming so please tell me how I can make the program print the message if I win or lose the game.

```
    String[] plays = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
    String botPlay = plays[new Random().nextInt(plays.length)];

    System.out.print("--------------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.print("Welcome to my Rock Paper Scissors game!");
    System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("\nPlay your move! Options are Rock Paper & Scissors!: ");
    String userPlay = scanner.next();

    if (userPlay.equals(botPlay)) {
        System.out.println("Tie!");
    } else if (userPlay.equals("scissors") && botPlay.equals("paper")) {
        System.out.println("You win! " + userPlay + " beats " + botPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equals("paper") && botPlay.equals("rock")) {
        System.out.println("You win! " + userPlay + " beats " + botPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equals("rock") && botPlay.equals("scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You win! " + userPlay + " beats " + botPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equals("paper") && userPlay.equals("scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equals("rock") && userPlay.equals("paper")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equals("scissors") && userPlay.equals("rock")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you printed `userPlay` to see what's in it? It could be a case issue, i.e.  `scissors` is not `Scissors` (capital s)

Comment: `(userPlay.equals("paper") && userPlay.equals("scissors"))` Can you come up with a string that is equal to both `"paper"` and `"scissors"` at the same time?

Comment: What did you try for debugging?

Answer (score 2):

*Copy Pasting* all game variants is *evil*. Look, having

```
 { "rock", "paper", "scissors" }
```

we can put *circular* (`a < b` means `a` loses `b`)

```
 "rock" < "paper" < "scissors" < "rock"
```

All we should do now is to compare indexes: `0 < 1 < 2 < 0`... To get `2 < 0` we can use *modulo arithmetics*

```
...
//TODO: check if userPlay is valid one

// You may want to use ArrayList instead of array from the beginning
int userIndex = java.util.Arrays.asList(plays).indexOf(userPlay);
int botIndex = java.util.Arrays.asList(plays).indexOf(botPlay);

int diff = (userIndex - botIndex + plays.length) % plays.length;

if (diff == 0) 
  System.out.println("Tie!");
else if (diff == 1)
  System.out.println("You win! " + userPlay + " beats " + botPlay);
else 
  System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
```

Comment: I like this approach! Using order of elements in the array to determine which beats the other is a nice way to simplify the logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

1. Your `String` array have lower case values and your prompt have capitalized values. This is obviously wrong and will make the other issues listed even worse...
2. You are comparing the strings with `equals()` rather than with `equalsIgnoreCase()`. This will make item #1 a non-issue. You should make this change to make your code a bit more robust.
3. You have no default clause in your code to catch potential erroneous conditions. For example, what is the result of your program if someone inputs "foo" from console? For example, I entered "Scissors" and the program felt through because it didn't match any of the cases. And it happened that "scissors" was the "random" value returned from the array, which should've resulted in a tie. Instead, it was inconclusive and nothing was printed out. For this reason, consider having an `else` block to handle inconclusive (erroneous) inputs.
4. Consider closing your scanner object immediately after calling `scanner.next()`. For this program, this is not an issue. But, in a larger program that might not end immediately, you could encounter an exception during processing the data and the I/O resource could remain open for much longer time. This is not super damaging, but could cause performance problems if this pattern is repeated in other parts of your program.

**UPDATE**: This is your code with my suggestions.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] plays = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
    String botPlay = plays[new Random().nextInt(plays.length)];

    System.out.print("--------------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.print("Welcome to my Rock Paper Scissors game!");
    System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("\nPlay your move! Options are rock, paper, or scissors!: ");
    String userPlay = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();

    if (userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase(botPlay)) {
        System.out.println("Tie!");
    } else if (userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors") && botPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
        System.out.println("You win! " + userPlay + " beats " + botPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") && botPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
        System.out.println("You win! " + userPlay + " beats " + botPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") && botPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You win! " + userPlay + " beats " + botPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") && userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") && userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors") && userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else {
        System.err.println(userPlay + " is an unexpected input.");
    }
```

Comment: Regarding #4: you should close your I/O resources, *except* for `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err`. If you close these, you won't be able to open them again in your entire program.

Comment: @MCEmperor I don't consider System resources YOUR resources. But, clarification is never a bad thing. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't address the bug the code has regarding the last three `if`s where OP wrote `userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase(...) && userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase(...)`. Those can never be true

Comment: @QBrute I didn't look at the game rules. I simply critiqued the coding in general. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what caused the error. You are compared the `userPlay` to `userPlay` instead of comparing it to `botPlay`. The condition will always be false.

```
else if (userPlay.equals("paper") && userPlay.equals("scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equals("rock") && userPlay.equals("paper")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else if(userPlay.equals("scissors") && userPlay.equals("rock")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    }
```

it should be:

```
else if (userPlay.equals("paper") && botPlay.equals("scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else if (userPlay.equals("rock") && botPlay.equals("paper")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
    } else if(userPlay.equals("scissors") && botPlay.equals("rock")) {
        System.out.println("You lose! " + botPlay + " beats " + userPlay);
```